# How to get percent combination of 5 colors from one single color code?

Tags: javascript, colors

I have a color code like `#8B8989`

And i also have 5 different Colors Code
Like

***Red
***Yellow
***Blue
***White
***Black

Now i have to mix this colors code to generate my targeted color code.

> What i have tried so far---

So far i tried to add those color hex code and try to achieve my targeted color but so far But its not giving what i expecting

```
function docalc(colorCode) {
let redCount = 0,
    yellowCount = 0;

let oldColor = document.getElementById("output_color_code").value;

if (oldColor != "") {

    c = (parseInt(oldColor, 16) + parseInt(colorCode, 16)).toString(16);
    console.log(c);
} else {
    c = colorCode;
}

document.getElementById("output_color_code").value = c;
document.getElementById("output").style.backgroundColor = c;

let givenColor = document.getElementById("given_color").value;
document.getElementById("given_output").style.backgroundColor = givenColor;
}
```

What i want to achieve is implemented in `https://trycolors.com/game` But i failed to find the algorithm of this

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow.  Can you show us a little bit of the code that you've been trying?

Comment: i updated the questing with my attempted code

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered doing a weighted mean of the components of the hex code?  That is, if you have added 3 of color A and 2 of color B, you could break each color down into its Red, Green, and Blue components using the hex code `#RRGGBB`.

Then, your new color would have `(3*Red Component of A + 2*Red Component of B) / (3+2)` for its red component, `(3*Green Component of A + 2*Green Component of B) / (3+2)` for its green component, and `(3*Blue Component of A + 2*Blue Component of B) / (3+2)`.

Keep in mind that each component of the 6-hexdigit color code has a maximum value of 0xFF (255 in decimal), so a sum would eventually just lead to white (#FFFFFF).  Additionally, if you don't separate components, then you will see some strange color behavior when one component overflows to another.

You might be able to use the following code as a guide:

```js
// keep track of how many times colors have already been added in some variable addCounter.  It probably shouldn't be global, but you'll need a way to keep track of this across many function calls.
var addCounter = 0;

function addColor(colorCode) {

  let oldColor = document.getElementById("output_color_code").value;

  if (oldColor != "") {
    // assuming oldColor and newColor do not contain leading '#'
    let oldRed = parseInt(oldColor.slice(0,2),16);
    let oldGreen = parseInt(oldColor.slice(2,4),16);
    let oldBlue = parseInt(oldColor.slice(4,6),16);

    let newRed = parseInt(newColor.slice(0,2),16);
    let newGreen = parseInt(newColor.slice(2,4),16);
    let newBlue = parseInt(newColor.slice(4,6),16);

    let avgRed = oldRed * addCounter + newRed;
    let avgGreen = oldGreen * addCounter + newGreen;
    let avgBlue = oldBlue * addCounter + newBlue;

    let c = avgRed.toString(16) + avgGreen.toString(16) + avgBlue.toString(16);
    console.log(c);
  } else {
    c = colorCode;
  }
  
  addCounter++;
  document.getElementById("output_color_code").value = c;
  document.getElementById("output").style.backgroundColor = "#"+c;

  let givenColor = document.getElementById("given_color").value;
  document.getElementById("given_output").style.backgroundColor =  "#"+c;
}
```